# Convención en Bilbao - sábado 3 noviembre 2018

Tags: discusión, encuentros-locales

### PARTICIPANTES

1. lois6b
2. Paula_plus_plus
3. Pablo Simon DiEstefano
4. blonfu
5. gdp (yo)

---

### 22/10/2018 (Última actualización)

---

No he recibido ninguna respuesta de SOes a los emails enviados, por lo que he decidido cancelarlo tal y como estaba pensado realizarlo (charlas etc...) para otra sera.

Pero tranquilos, sigo manteniendo la opción de visitar Bilbao y hacer cosas todos unidos, tomar algo o ir de poteo jajaja

Para apuntarse: https://goo.gl/forms/5jltHxuHjTHQcCB52

---

### 20/09/2018

---

Sala de chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82969/convencion-bilbao

---

Lo primero presentarme, soy Iñaki y llevo ya un añito por SOes.

Hace unos meses estuve indagando en cómo realizar una pequeña "quedada", ¿y la verdad? me motivó bastante la idea. Creo que podría darle un toque más serio poniendo alguna charla etc...

Tengo ya disponibles instalaciones, una entidad que nos de soporte públicamente y material.

Desde SOes ya se me comento que podrían aportar swag, los anuncios del evento en el sitio y redes sociales, comida y bebida. Sobre todo swag jajaja.

Mi idea es hacerlo para Noviembre o Diciembre, pero depende un poco de la gente que os intereseis claro.

Tema instalaciones, no tengo problemas para hacer una reserva de instalaciones municipales en Barakaldo (Cerquita de Bilbao, y en metro a nada).

Pero claro,... me falta la gente!

Por lo tanto, si vais comentando quienes sois de cerca o estaríais interesados en asistir, genial :)

---

### Fecha

**03/11/2018**

(Se ha barajado esta opción debido a los festivos, así poder facilitar los tiempos de viaje y compaginar mejor con el trabajo. Si teneis alguna otra propuesta, adelante).

---

### Lugar

**Instalaciones municipales** del ayuntamiento de **Barakaldo** (a 5 minutos del metro).

Mapa al final de esta publicación.

(lo mismo que lo anterior, se escuchan propuestas).

---

### Actividades

Se han propuesto diversas actividades como (están por definir TODAS todavía):

- C++ (Tema: Por definir / Formato: Charla-taller / Ponente: @Paula_plus_plus)
- Analitica Web (Tema: Por definir / Formato: Por definir / Ponente: @lois6b)
- Lanzamiento de CDs (Formato: Competición [risas])
- Gincanas..??

[Drive Excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19BrU8tWZRqKM5_dmfs2IKynpCny3RPmp9ILdCp1CQ5E/edit?usp=sharing)

Todo aquel interesado en presentar, exponerse, dar el cante o lo que sea, que no lo dude!

---

### MAPA

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2903.967753562504!2d-2.9972149840820332!3d43.29399697913526!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0xd4e5a74f5615bdb%3A0xc078c258f33517b8!2sCasa+de+Cultura+Clara+Campoamor!5e0!3m2!1ses!2ses!4v1537427656430" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Yo, dependiendo de fechas etc etc...me apunto.

Comment: ¡Qué buena idea! ¿Sería sobre alguna tecnología en concreto o algo general? ¿Se podría mirar algún tipo de alojamiento para los que vivimos algo lejos?

Comment: Yo, como Pikoh, depende de la fecha me apunto fijo. **Fin de semana** estaría bien. Y como dice Fedorqui, habria que planear la tematica, proponer **charlas o debates**.

Comment: Yo tenia pensado hacer alguna charla "general" porque probablemente, si somos pocos, tocar lenguajes diferentes es dividir a la gente. En plan clean code y cosas asi.

Comment: @fedorqui pues lo de alojamientos no lo se, pero se puede mirar.

Comment: @GDP Excelente tu propuesta, incluso puedes escribir a nuestro CM y tal vez podrías tener un poco de patrocinio de parte de SOes con las pizzas y las sodas :-)

Comment: @Jorgesys ya hable con el y me comento que si, que podríamos tener publicidad y comida y bebida y así.

Comment: @GDP excelente me da mucho gusto Iñaki  (•‿•)  , seguramente tendrá buena asistencia y será un éxito el evento!

Comment: Sería una gran experiencia, si las fechas me cuadrasen ahí tienes a uno de Zaragoza. =)

Comment: ¿cómo podemos los interesados estar al tanto sin tener que estar visitando ésta página?

Comment: Tomando los votos positivos como personas dispuestas a ir... ¿Cuál es el número necesario para conocer más datos, como fechas, lugares concretos?

Comment: @gavioto20 podriamos hacer un chat de SOes para este fin, donde se vaya actualizando la informacion que vayamos consiguiendo. Quienes quieran que se les notifique, le añadimos un ping (@) y así se puede estar al tanto.

Comment: @lois6b me parece buena idea, a mi me gustaría estar al tanto

Comment: Se ha creado [la sala de chat Convencion Bilbao](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82969/convencion-bilbao) para hablar de este tema. Los detalles definitivos se añadirán a la respuesta de esta publicacion.

Comment: ¿ Habrá medalla `No Soy Un Robot` ? Molaría :-)

Comment: @Trauma si, estaria guay. pero se require de al menos 15 asistentes para que cuente además de algun empleado de SO organice o participe. [+info](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/117/not-a-robot)

Comment: Otro mas que intentara asistir

Comment: @fedorqui cuanto suele tardar en salir en la seccion de destacados? Lleva ya 1 h

Comment: @GDP Si se puediera que graben los talleres para los que no podes ir

Comment: @Trauma sería genial, también sería genial que en México se hiciera uno algún día

Comment: Gran iniciativa, si me es posible asistiré :thumbs_up

Comment: @EmilianoPamont se ha organizado algo similar en las ciudades de CDMX y Monterrey, México.

Comment: @gdp te envíe un mensaje, podemos seguir con el plan para este evento

Comment: @JuanM Respondido al mail :)

Comment: @DIe seguimos adelante aunque no sea de manera "seria" https://goo.gl/forms/KuFpDYn4yeZQ0FO93